I have two measures in PowerBi - one that calculates the number and one the percent. How can I concatenate please to show e.g. "3 (3.9%")
I would like to concatenate the two measures below please to show a number then the percentage in brackets on a card in Power BI.

NumberWithin3Days = DIVIDE([AdmissionsWithin30Days],[TotalReferrals])
PercentageWithin3Days = DIVIDE([AdmissionsWithin30Days],[TotalReferrals],0)+0

Can anyone help please?

You can create a new measure to concat that two measures. This might help you get your answer :
Concatenated_Measure = 
VAR NumberWithin3Days = [NumberWithin3Days]
VAR PercentageWithin3Days = [PercentageWithin3Days]
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(
        VALUES('AnyTable'[AnyColumn]),  -- Use any table you have and column
        NumberWithin3Days & 
        " (" & 
        FORMAT(PercentageWithin3Days, "0.00%") & 
        ")", 
        ", "
    )

